# Mysql Date_ADD intervalos no mesmo código PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET expira = DATE_ADD(expira, INTERVAL $diasc DAY, $horac HOUR and $minutoc MINUTE and $segundosc SECOND), expira_manutencao = '0' WHERE expira_manutencao = '1'";
```

Gostaria de usar o interval de day our minute e second de uma vez como acima, porém não ta dando certo.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que poderia ser assim:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET 
expira = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(expira, INTERVAL $diasc DAY), INTERVAL $horac HOUR), INTERVAL $minutoc MINUTE), INTERVAL $segundosc SECOND), 
expira_manutencao = '0' 
WHERE expira_manutencao = '1'";
```